# Obtain a collection of generic types from PagedCollectionView

Tags: c#

Suppose I had a PageCollectionView of ItemType, where T is some user class that was defined in the project. My ItemType class has a property called IsSelected that I want to perform a query on. Effectively, this is what I want to do:

```
var objects = Source.SourceCollection.OfType<ItemType<>>().Where(t => t.IsSelected);
```

Of course this doesn't work because the ItemType generic needs a type. I can't specify the real type for the collection as I don't know it at this level (plus I don't want to hardcode the real type anyway, defeats the purpose of having the generic). Most likely, I could figure out a way using reflection, but I'd rather not for readability. Is there someway to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could `ItemType<dynamic>` work?

Comment: I think the runtime would just consider this to be ItemType<object>, which is not true in this case (not sure of the contravariance type definition rules within a generic collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not define an interface?

```
public interface ISelectable
{
   pubilc bool IsSelected { get; }
}

public class ItemType<T> : ISelectable
{
   ...
}

var objects = Source.SourceCollection
   .OfType<ISelectable>()
   .Where(t => t.IsSelected);
```

Comment: It is true, simplicity is the key to brilliance. Thanks Richard!